# Count number of foreign key values referred

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. **Table 1** and **Table 2**.

`id2` in **Table 2** is the foreign key of the primary key `id1` in **Table 1**.

How do I find if all the values of `id1` column are used in `id2` column?

If none of them are used, how many values of `id1` are used in `id2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are only interested in finding out how many ids are used,

```
SELECT COUNT(table2.id2) FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON
table1.id = table2.id2
```

This is thanks to an often overlooked feature of COUNT, instead of COUNT(*) you can specify a column name and COUNT(column_name) will only count NOT NULL values of that column.

Comment: Works. Thanks a lot @e4c5

Comment: Gad to have been of help